# Must provide HTTP header "Authorization" or URL parameter "authorization"

Tags: node.js, api, axios, dropbox-api

I am trying to download a File from dropbox using Dropbox APIs. I use the code below

```
axios.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ${MY token}',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg': { path: '/Thillai Maharajan.jpg' }
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log("RESPONSE: ",response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("ERROR RES",error);
});
```

But it says **data: 'Error in call to API function "files/download": Must provide HTTP header "Authorization" or URL parameter "authorization".'**

Can anyone help?

You can refer the Dropbox API Document at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer. I have to Stringify the `Dropbox-API-Arg` Parameter using `JSON.stringify()`. Because The header argument could not be a JSON. I changed that and it worked.

`'Dropbox-API-Arg' : JSON.stringify({"path":"/Thillai Maharajan.jpg"})`